# RobotFramework - Compare query result with result from another file

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I've a script using RobotFramework that makes a lot of database tests. Currently, I am trying to add a new test case that executes a query test from another Python script (called raw_data.py). The raw_data.py is very simple and it only have this code:

```
query_begin = """SELECT *  
          FROM my_Table"""

def get_queries_list(query):
    result = query.replace('\n','').strip()
    return result

query_result = get_queries_list(query_begin)
print(query_result)
```

So what I want to do is to execute the result (the query) from the previous script using robotframework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     raw_data.py

Suite Setup         Connect To Database       pymysql  ${DBName}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPass}   ${DBHost}   ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown      Disconnect From Database

*** Variables ***
${DBName}   myDB
${DBUser}   user
${DBPass}   pass
${DBHost}   hostname
${DBPort}   port
${Query}    'SELECT * FROM DEV.personal_tasks'

*** Test Cases ***
Compare the target data with the source data
    ${output}=  Execute SQL String get_queries_list(query) 
    log to console  ${output}
    should be equal as strings  ${output}   10
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
No keyword with name 'Execute SQL String get_queries_list(${Query})' found.
```

However, the keyword 'Execute SQL String' already exists... what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Read the error carefully. It's not saying the keyword "Execute SQL String" doesn't exist, it's saying that a keyword named "Execute SQL String get_queries_list(${Query})" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing at least 2 spaces between `Execute SQL String` and `get_queries_list(query)` so it evaluates it as a whole, which will then fail and return the error that no such keyword exists.

EDIT:

You also need to save the query into a variable that you later pass to `Execute SQL String`:

```
${query}=    get_queries_list(query)
Execute SQL String    ${query}
```

Comment: you're right :) However it doesn't execute the query it thinks that "get_queries_list(${Query})" is the query and it gives me a syntax error